# How to make document keep View.ShadeEditableRanges Property in Visual Basic

Tags: vba

I am brand new to Visual Basic, but I am putting together a macro that allowed me to quickly make letterheads for each department in my organization and then protect the header and footer, so that users only edit the text of their letters. But this creates a yellow background behind whatever they type.

This code removes the yellow background:

```
ActiveWindow.View.ShadeEditableRanges = False
```

But once the document is closed and re-opened, the yellow shading re-appears.
This also doesn't make it stay:

```
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShadeEditableRanges = False
```

I successfully created a macro that runs each time the document is opened:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShadeEditableRanges = False
End Sub
```

This correctly removes the highlight, but, of course, it causes a security alert for most users. This is undesireable for documents that will also be distributed to an external audience.

Is there a way to make this setting stick with the document?

Comment: Hmm. Unable to reproduce the yellow background. Are you setting that in the code? As sample word doc would definitely help. Also please confirm the MS Word version you are using.

Comment: MS Word 2010.
The yellow background displays by default. I can post more details when I return to work on Monday.

Comment: Here is a dropbox folder containing a sample Word document with the yellow background: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/v6b2r6ddk9djf6a/eUdnHU1s2h/sample%20protected%20word%20document.docx

Comment: Ok Can you share the macro that you are using?

Comment: I just added the code to my original question. It works, but of course it sets off warnings from the macro security settings. I guess I am looking for a way to change this setting, and save it to the document without having to run a macro each time the document opens.

Answer (score 0):

If the property is lost upon closing and reopening I would go for setting it whenever the document is opened.

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
    ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShadeEditableRanges = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Coincidentally, this is exactly the same macro I coded shortly after posting my question. Unfortunately, this requires everyone who uses the letterhead to approve the macro. Also, many people will be using this letterhead to send documents electronically, so anyone who reads the word document would have to run the macro, too.